# How can I make this selected object cut the objects in the background?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

[image]

So I'm designing transfer decals for a club. The selected portion in white needs to be transparent, but it also needs to cut out the background shapes in order to have a transparent border for the font below the selection. I've tried a "knockout" tutorial but that didn't give me the results I wanted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Transparency Masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transparency-blending-modes.html).

Make sure your foreground shape (the cutout) color is set to white and in the foreground (above the other objects/paths).

[image: shapes]

Now select all (both) of your objects and open the *Transparency Panel*

**Window → Transparency** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Click on <kbd>Make Mask</kbd> and uncheck **Clip** and select **Invert Mask**

[image: make mask]

Result:

[image: result]

You can also learn more about this by watching [this video](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-opacity-masks-transparency.html) from Adobe.